# DOM Javascript - getting cell content

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I'm attempting to retrieve multiple elements from inside a table through my Chrome Extension, to make an average for each column (it's a grade sheet).

The table looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

My JavaScript script loop is currently:

```
var countChildren = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel').childElementCount;
for (var i = 0; i < countChildren; i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    var countTRchildren = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].childElementCount;
    for (var tr = 0; tr < countTRchildren; tr++) {
      var x = GetinnerHTML.rows[i].cells[tr];
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
}
```

It returns (for each cell):

```
<td class="textCenter">
   <div class="textCenter" 
   title="XPRSFag: 4831B Samtidshistorie Kilde: Karakter Vægt: 1,5">
   4
   </div>
</td>
```

The elements I need from each cell is:

- The innerHTML of DIV (In this case "4", which is the grade).
- The last character of the title's string (In this case "1,5" which is the grade weight).

As mentioned, I need to get an average for each column, preferably with the "Karakter Vægt: 1,5" as it's "Grade weight" in %.

So I need the inner loop to return:

```
x = ["4", "1,5"];
```

I am fairly new to scripting in JavaScript, so I still have a lot to learn. :)

Thanks for taking your time to read this, I'm open to any suggestions, and if I can be more accurate in any way, let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you actually need to target `<div>` inside the cell; query its text content and title value. One possible way:

```
for (var tdi = 0; tdi < countTRchildren; tdi++) {
  var td = GetinnerHTML.rows[i].cells[tdi];
  var div = td.querySelector('div');
  var textContent = div.textContent;
  var title = div.getAttribute('title');
  var no = title.match(/([0-9,.]+$)/);

  // there should be a collecting code instead
  console.log(title.trim(), no && no[0]);
}
```

But actually, I'd reorganize your code into two sections.

The first one should only bother about *collecting* cell elements and organizing them in some kind of data structure. For example, all the cell innards seem to have `div.textContent` selector - so they can be collected with one simple `querySelectorAll` call.

The second one should only bother about retrieving the information from the given cell. Ideally, it should be a function receiving a cell as an argument, and returning an object with required fields.

Comment: Hm, I will look into this. It was probably worth mentioning there's multiple tbody elements on the page - which also has div elements using the "textCenter" class. Which just makes it even more awkward, as I need to select only the div elements inside one tbody...

Comment: That's the whole point of dividing the code: you only have to worry about collecting the right number of cells in the first section, not the data retrieval. The particular task is easy to solve: just target the `tbody` element you need first, then call `querySelectorAll` from it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I'm now getting ex: '"1,5" "4"'. So now I'll work towards sorting the data. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Fully working script:
https://pastebin.com/25V4P12A

```
    /**
 * @Author: Toke Raabjerg <TokeDK>
 * @Date:   29-Aug-2018
 * @Email:  *
 * @Project: *
 * @Last modified by:   TokeDK
 * @Last modified time: 09-Sep-2018
 */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//                             CHECKS                             //
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

chrome.storage.local.get([
  'Lectio_gradeAverage'
], function (result) {
  if (result.Lectio_gradeAverage == true || result.Lectio_gradeAverage == undefined) {

      run();

      } else {
          var targetx = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
          var trx = document.createElement('tr');
          trx.style = "text-align:center; font-weight:600;";
          trx.id = "average";
          trx.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Husk du kan benytte gennemsnitsberegneren! Aktiver under indstillinger.</td>";
          targetx.appendChild(trx);
    }
  }
);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//                         DATA STRUCTURE                         //
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

function run () {
var times2 = 0; var times3 = 0; var times4 = 0; var times5 = 0; var times6 = 0;
var calcAverage2 = 0; var calcAverage3 = 0; var calcAverage4 = 0; var calcAverage5 = 0; var calcAverage6 = 0;
var tables = 0;

function calculateData (tr, div) {
  var grade = div.textContent;
  var title = div.title;
  var weightStr = title.split(":").pop();
  var weight = parseFloat(weightStr.replace(',','.').replace(' ',''));
  var average = grade * weight;

  if (tr == 2) {
    times2 = times2 + 1;
    calcAverage2 = calcAverage2 + average;
  }
      if (tr == 3) {
        times3 = times3 + 1;
        calcAverage3 = calcAverage3 + average;
      }
          if (tr == 4) {
            times4 = times4 + 1;
            calcAverage4 = calcAverage4 + average;
          }
              if (tr == 5) {
                times5 = times5 + 1;
                calcAverage5 = calcAverage5 + average;
              }
                  if (tr == 6) {
                    times6 = times6 + 1;
                    calcAverage6 = calcAverage6 + average;
                  }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//                               LOOP                             //
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].id = "karakter_tabel";

  var getChildren = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel').childElementCount;
  var GetinnerHTML = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel');
  countChildren = getChildren - 1;

  for(var i = 0; i < countChildren; i++)
  {
    //if (i != 0) {
      var countTRchildren = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].childElementCount;
        for(var tr = 0; tr < countTRchildren; tr++)
          {
            var inner = GetinnerHTML.rows[i].cells[tr];
            div = inner.querySelector('div');
            if (div != null) {calculateData (tr, div);}
          //}
    }
  }


/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//                     DOM & DATA STRUCTURE                       //
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  if (countChildren > 2) {
    var target = document.getElementById('karakter_tabel');
      var trd = document.createElement('tr');
      trd.style = "text-align:center; font-weight:600;";
      trd.id = "average";
      trd.innerHTML = "<tr><td></td><td>Gennemsnit (Er dette forkert? <a href='#' target='_blank'>Klik her</a>)</td>";//<td><div>" + average2 + "</div></td><td><div>" + average3 + "</td></div><td><div>" + average4 +"</div></td><td><div>" + average5 + "</td></div></tr>";
      target.appendChild(trd);


    var averagex2 = calcAverage2 / times2; if(isNaN(averagex2)) {averagex2 = 0;}  else {
      var average2 = averagex2.toFixed(2);
      var two = document.createElement('td'); two.innerHTML = "<div>"+ average2 + "</div>";
      document.getElementById('average').appendChild(two);
    }

    var averagex3 = calcAverage3 / times3; if(isNaN(averagex3)) {averagex3 = 0;}  else {
      var average3 = averagex3.toFixed(2);
      var three = document.createElement('td'); three.innerHTML = "<div>"+ average3 + "</div>";
      document.getElementById('average').appendChild(three);
    }

    var averagex4 = calcAverage4 / times4; if(isNaN(averagex4)) {averagex4 = 0;}  else {
      var average4 = averagex4.toFixed(2);
      var four = document.createElement('td'); four.innerHTML = "<div>"+ average4 + "</div>";
      document.getElementById('average').appendChild(four);
    }

    var averagex5 = calcAverage5 / times5; if(isNaN(averagex5)) {averagex5 = 0;}  else {
      var average5 = averagex5.toFixed(2);
      var five = document.createElement('td'); five.innerHTML = "<div>"+ average5 + "</div>";
      document.getElementById('average').appendChild(five);
    }

    var averagex6 = calcAverage6 / times6; if(isNaN(averagex6)) {averagex6 = 0;} else {
      var average6 = averagex6.toFixed(2);
      var six = document.createElement('td'); six.innerHTML = "<div>"+ average6 + "</div>";
      document.getElementById('average').appendChild(six);
    }
  }
}
```